# Password does not match for user "postgres" after deleting postgresql from local machine

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I am running an application in 3 separated docker containers. One for postgresql, another one for Django and the third one for nginx. In my `settings.py` I retrieve data for my db settings from `.env` file like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

I used `sqlite` for development but was building docker image using postgresql and it was working perfectly fine. Then for testing purposes I connected postgresql to django as development database with the exactly same settings. But after I returned to sqlite and built another image with this db settings it actually started returning password error.

```
db_1     |      Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
db_1     | 2020-09-20 16:39:02.730 UTC [36] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1     | 2020-09-20 16:39:02.730 UTC [36] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static:
  media:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    image: ashowlsky/foodgram:v3.8
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn foodgram.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./static:/code/static/
      - ./media:/code/media/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.2
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./static:/code/static/
      - ./media:/code/media/
    depends_on:
      - web
```

What could be the reason for it?

Comment: and what the content of `./.env` is ?

Comment: Most likely reason is that you removed the Postgres cluster and then built an new one and did not add back the passwords. FYI, to save global data from a Postgres cluster use `pg_dumpall -g`.  This will save the `ROLE` information including passwords.